# Have a bot mention all users in a Discord voice channel

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

Does anyone know of a way to return all users within a Discord voice channel for the purpose of having a bot mention them all in a text message? I do not mean the `@everyone` mention.
For example, if players A, B, and C were all in the same voice channel, and one of them typed `.vote` (my bot's trigger command), the bot would create a new vote which mentions players A, B, and C. The vote closes once all mentioned players have reacted to the vote.

I'm pretty new to making discord bots... I have looked through the Discord Developer Portal SDK, but did not find anything on this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some work looking in the manual, I found something you can use.

There is a class named `VoiceChannel`, this one has a snowflake with all members in it. Every member in that snowflake is an instance of `GuildMember`.

So, if I'm not wrong, you can use this code:

```js
VoiceChannel.members.forEach(function(guildMember, guildMemberId) {
   console.log(guildMemberId, guildMember.user.username);
   Channel.send("<@" + guildMemberId + ">");
})
```

Please note that you can't just copy paste the code and expect it to work. You need to change both `VoiceChannel` and `Channel` to the proper objects.

Read this as reference:

> https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel

Comment: Thanks. I thought I was looking in the correct place, but the link you posted is definitely the API where I need to be looking